# VScode typing echo

Tags: visual-studio-code

My VS code started to echo all what I'm typing. I think it is some settings to make video tutorials.
How can I get rid of it?

Here is example when I typed few Spaces.
[image]

Thy same goes for Ctrl, Function Key, etc
[image]

It also has some strange behavior - for example it absolutely ignores keyboard key "q". It accepts "Q" but not lower case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've activated the [screencast mode](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_31#_screencast-mode).

To disable it, press <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+P</kbd> (Win, Linux) or <kbd>Cmd+Shift+P</kbd> (Mac) and search for Toggle Screencast Mode.

Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to deactivate it.
(Repeat the steps to activate it)

Comment: Thanks. It looks that by accident I assigned this screencats mode to the "q" character.